# Recursive SQL using Rails 4 (modeling)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, recursion

I read a tutorial, but I did not understand properly. I will quote it here and present the problem that seek to solve.

[Tutorial](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord)

My problem:
I'm doing a forum that can have various categories and subcategories. Then decide to use SQL Recursive PostgreSQL to facilitate me and not pollute my db with unnecessary tables.
Suppose I have a table `categories`, and it has the `categories_id` field. Then the model would look something like this:

```
  attr_accessible :parent

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => 'categories_id'

  scope :top_level, where(:categories_id => nil)
```

1. I did not understand fully if `parent` and `children` are a field in the table or not.
2. Why did he have to create a `attr_accessible :parent`?
3. Why the creation of `scope`?

Comment: I think you have some confusion going on here with `parent_id`/`categories_id`. The latter is not in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `parent_id` is a field. There are no fields for `children`.
2. So that `parent_id` is mass-assignable.
3. for more readable code. This

   ```
   @articles = Article.top_level
   ```

   looks way clearer than an obscure

   ```
   @articles = Article.where(parent_id: nil)
   ```